# How to perform string interpolation on string returned from DB PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string-interpolation

I am trying to figure out how to make this work. I am currently storing a string with a dynamic variable in it in a DB. The string is stored like this, and it is associated with a thank you message:

`"Thank you for visiting $location->name"`

When I retrieve it, I am doing this:

`$thankyou = Thankyou::where('action', $request->get('action');`

My hope was that I would be able to then dynamically get and set the `location` variable

`$location = Location::where('id', $request->get('id'))->first()`

And then return `$thankyou->message` (which has the value of the string above) and have it work as intended.

In full, my code looks like this

```
$thankyou = Thankyou::where('action', $request->get('action');
// $thankyou->message yields "Thank you for visiting $location->name"
$location = Location::where('id', $request->get('id'))->first();
return $thankyou->message;
```

But, instead of correctly parsing the `$location` variable, this code simply returns the string stored in the DB. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an accessor insted, as the whole approach is not completely right. Let's save your message is saved like: "Thank you for visiting %location_name%"

```
public function getUpdatedMessageAttribute()
{
    $location = Location::where('id', request()->get('id'))->first();
    return str_replace('%location_name%', $location->name, $this->message);
}
```

You can develop the way you receive your parameters to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Usually placeholders are used. For example:

```
$variables = [
  'LOCATION_NAME' => 'New York',
  'OTHER_VAR' => 'Test'
];
$string = 'Thank you for visiting {LOCATION_NAME}. {OTHER_VAR}';

foreach($variables as $key => $var){
  $string = \Str::replaceFirst('{'.$key.'}', $var, $string);
}

return $string;
```